# How to change entries based on condition in a file ansible

Tags: jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I need to replace the entries in a file if those are not correct and also need to add if the entry is missing. For example i have three `nameserver` which needs to be there on every host like below:

Below are the correct entries:

```
nameserver 192.168.148.86
nameserver 172.168.194.35
nameserver 172.228.49.201
```

So, if the above entries are on the hosts in the `resolv.conf` then do not change anything, however, if there is change in the `IP address` apart from the above then these entries needs to be replaced but the sequence always be in the same order.

Lets, suppose if there are only two entries in the file from the above ones then we need to copy third entry as well.

Below is my File looks like, but to be sure, we don't want to change the very first entry in the file ie `search udl.in-nda02.tpv.com udl.nl-cdc01.tpv.com udl.us-cdc01.tpv.com in-blr01.tpv.com` at all.

**File:**

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search udl.in-nda02.tpv.com udl.nl-cdc01.tpv.com udl.us-cdc01.tpv.com in-blr01.tpv.com

nameserver 192.168.148.85
nameserver 172.168.194.34
nameserver 172.228.49.200
```

**Playbook**

```
---
- name: Play to correct the config for NTP clients
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Changing the ntp server configuration on the client
    lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/resolv.conf
      regexp: '{{ item.From }}'
      line: '{{ item.To }}'
      state: present
      backup: yes

    with_items:
    - { From: 'nameserver 192.168.148.85', To: '192.168.148.86'}
    - { From: 'nameserver 172.168.194.34', To: 'nameserver 172.168.194.35'}
    notify: file_dns

  handlers:
  - name: file_dns
    service:
      name: nscd
      state: restarted
```

I come with above code, which works for me if the entries are same across all the hosts.

How i could make this playbook more dynamic to meet the conditions as i explained.

I tried with template but that also removes the very first entry in the file ie `search udl.in-nda02.tpv.com udl.nl-cdc01.tpv.com udl.us-cdc01.tpv.com in-blr01.tpv.com` at all.

Comment: A common solution to this is to generate the target file (`/etc/resolv.conf`) using the `template` module, rather than using `lineinfile`.

Comment: @larsks, thanks for the input, i tried that but somehow that removes my `search udl.in-nda02.tpv.com udl.nl-cdc01.tpv.com udl.us-cdc01.tpv.com in-blr01.tpv.com` which may be changed on various hosts and that's what i would like avoid. would appreciate any idea.

Comment: Make that a host specific variable, and include that in your template.